# What is a unit test and how do I do one in Visual Studio with C# .Net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

OK so I have the following classes in C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass("Hello World");
        myClass.WriteToConsole();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string textToEncapsulate)
    {
        MyProperty = textToEncapsulate;
    }

    public void WriteToConsole()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyProperty);
    }
}
```

Three questions:

1. What is unit testing?
2. Would unit testing be beneficial in the above example?
3. How would I go about 'Unit Testing' the above example?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research at all?

Comment: Reason for my close-vote: this question is overly broad and lacks evidence of "what you have tried".

Comment: Yes, I've found lots of general info but I am looking for an answer within the context of .Net and Visual Studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*1. What is unit testing?*

Manual testing is time consuming. It can be hard to run the exact same set of tests each time by hand to make sure that all parts of your code are functioning as expected. When testing a complete product by hand, it's also really hard to test all code paths.

How would you test the reaction of your code when a database is unavailable? Or when some erroneous data is stored? That would take quite some time to get right.

Unit Testing means that we start testing the smallest possible parts of our code. And to make sure we can do this easily we automate the process. This means that we write test code that tests our production code.

For example:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 5;

Calculator c = new Calculator();
int sum = c.Sum(a, b);

Assert.AreEqual(8, sum);
```

This tests assures that your Sum function on your Calculator class is working correctly.

Now, let's say that you want to optimize the inner workings of your Calculator class. You start changing and optimizing code. After each change you run your unit test and when they all succeed you know you haven't broken any code.

Let's say that in production a user submits a bug report for your Calculator. Your first step will be to write a unit test that shows this bug. After the new test is failing (because the bug is still there!) you fix the bug, the unit tests succeeds and you can be certain that this bug will never come back.

This safety harness is one of the biggest benefits of unit tests.

*2 Would unit testing be beneficial in the above example? 3 How would I go about 'Unit Testing' the above example?*

Unit Testing is a good practice. It helps you prove that your code is working. In your example however, it would be hard to test the code.

An output to the console is not something that can be easily tested. If however, you would abstract the idea of Console.WriteLine then your code becomes better testable.

Writing Unit Tests is actually quite simple. The problem is writing code that can actually be tested.

A better testable version of your code would be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(new ConsoleOutputService(), "Hello World");
        myClass.WriteToConsole();
    }
}

public interface IOutputService
{

    void WriteLine(string MyProperty);
}

public class ConsoleOutputService : IOutputService
{
    public void WriteLine(string MyProperty)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyProperty);
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private IOutputService _outputService;
    private string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyClass(IOutputService outputService, string textToEncapsulate)
    {
        _outputService = outputService;
        MyProperty = textToEncapsulate;
    }

    public void WriteToConsole()
    {
        _outputService.WriteLine(MyProperty);

    }
}
```

You have replaced your direct dependency on the Console with an interface. When unit testing this code, you could supply a fake for your IOutputService and check the outcome.

A really good book is [xUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/). It shows the common pitfalls in writing unit test and patterns to avoid/fix them.

I also [wrote a blog](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.nl/2012/03/unit-testing-hell-or-heaven.html) myself about testable code a couple of months ago. It's somewhat more advanced but maybe you can get something out of it. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thankyou! This answer made a lot of sense, worth all of the downvotes =)

Answer (score 3):

The class you proposed is not so testable, since it works directly on the console. It would be different if you change teh method `WriteToConsole(TextWriter out)`;. In this case you can mock the TextWriter and make some assertion that the class output to console exactly what you expect. The idea is that if you write testable code, you write better code, because working for testability make your code more reusable. Even if in your case making a unit test seems a little silly, having a test proving that simple behaviour works make you safer in case of further modification, done by you or others, that can potentially change as a side effect the expectations you have defined. Please note that I have proposed you to use a simple TextWriter as an additional parameter to make your class testable: it is my opinion you have to do the simplest effort to make your class testable, and since TextWriter is mockable you achieve the benefit of testing without rewriting your entire code, that is usually good.